# AngularJS Charts - How to load External JSON data without Error

Tags: angularjs, json, charts

Firstly, apologies for the *really* rookie question. I have just jumped into the world of java, JSON, etc, and it's all **very** new to me.
I have looked all over but just cannot figure out where the problem is here.

I am trying to display a bubble chart (Simple eh!), with data sourced externally (qcdata2.json)
I *think* the loading of data works but suspect the JSON is malformed. I really cannot figure out why it's failing. Do you know?
I consistently get the following error:
**angular.js:14525 Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?p0=%5B%7B40%2C10%2C20%7D%2C%7B10%2C40%2C50%7D%5D%0D%0A&p1=%7B%7D**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Graph View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="node_modules/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div id="container" class="container" width=100%>
        <div class="row" ng-controller="BubbleCtrl">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Bubble chart</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <canvas class="chart chart-bubble" chart-data="data" chart-colors="colors" chart-options="options"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js']);

    myApp.controller('BubbleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.series=[];
        $scope.data=[];

        $scope.series.push('Series 1');
        $scope.data.push({
            "x": 40,
            "y": 10,
            "r": 20
        });

        //Now try adding Series 2 data
        $scope.series.push('Series 2');
        $scope.data.push({
            "x": 50,
            "y": 30,
            "r": 10
        });
        console.log($scope.data);

        //So, now try the external data thing
        $http.get('qcdata2.json').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("It worked!");
            $scope.series.push('Series 3');
            $scope.data.push(response.data);
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
            throw error;
        }

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON File (qcdata2,json) Contents:
{
    "data": [{
        "x": 10,
        "y": 20,
        "r": 5
    }]
}

Comment: if you `console.log(response.data)` in your `successCallback` is the data in the format you expect? ie, `[{x:40,y:10,r:20}]`

Comment: it doesn't get that far.. The parsing process seems to fail, so jumps straight to errorCallback. Tis one has me stumped, have tried everything... I wonder if this is an object vs array thing..

Comment: I sorted it, thanks to the helpful comments here. The Json was malformed,  but even worse, I was chasing my tail for HOURS as chrome, for some reason, insisted on caching the external json file loaded in previous sessions, despite any later changes. IE works well, and refreshes everytime. If only I had known..

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not properly formatted.
Here's how it should look like:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "x": 40,
        "y": 10,
        "r": 20
    }]
}
```

Comment: I've made you a punker example of how it should work. Check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/N7e5guh0U1ODoCvoLxvk?p=preview

Comment: now THATS useful! thanks. It leads into the next phase. What I am trying to achieve is to export data from a test management tool, and using a treeview, select specific data to display on the bubble chart. No idea how to do that yet.